# iOS 16 bug or incorrect way to be changing @State property

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, ios15, ios16

One of my packages that I maintain uses `editingChanged` on `TextField()` to detect when the field is actually focused and then modify the text. This has worked fine on other iOS versions but in iOS16 it doesn't seem you're able to update a value from within a `TextField` if it's being used by that `TextField`

**Is this the wrong way to update an `@State` property and it was bugged before 16 or is this something that was bugged in 16?** If it's bugged, no big deal... but if I'm doing something wrong, of course I would like to fix that.

Below is a simplified version of what my package does, remember this was working before 16. You can even load it into a 15.5 sim and a 16 sim and see the difference.

```
@State private var text = ""

var body: some View {
    Form {
        TextField("", text: $text) { editingChanged in
            text = "Should update text, but doesn't."
        }
        
        Button(action: {
            text = "This will update without issue."
        }) {
            Text("Manually update via button.")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The `TextField.init(_:text:onEditingChanged:)` has been deprecated since iOS 15, so it is guaranteed anymore to be operable. It can remain for older OS versions support but for new the code must be migrated to new one.

Comment: @Asperi Thank you, looks like I'll update and just stop support for iOS 14.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the following:

```
TextField("", text: $text)
    .onChange(of: text) { 
       text = "should work now"
    }
```